# How to access a class member variable from a different class in c++

Tags: c++, member-access

I have the following 2 class header files (A.h and B.h), with a function inside each:

class A
{
public:
double f(double);
};

class B
{
public:
double g(double);
};

Here are their corresponding cpp files:

## include "A.h"

```
double A::f(double variable1)
{
// do stuff on variable 1
}
```

## include "B.h"

## include "A.h"

```
double B::g(double variable2)
{
// do stuff on variable2 using f from A
}
```

I would like to use function f (from A) inside function g (in B). How do I do this?

Comment: Are you satisfied with the presentation of this question?

Comment: By indenting the code-section in your question, you can make it look like code.  (readup on markdown syntax!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options:

1. Make the functions `static`. You can do that if the functions don't use any non-static members of the class. Then you can call `A::f(variable2)` within `B::g`
2. Have `B` *inherit* from `A`. Then you can access `A::f(variable2)` from `B::g`
3. Have an *instance* of `A` as a *member* of `B`. You then access `A::f(variable2)` from that instance.
4. Pass an instance of `A` into the function `B::g`. Access the function via that instance.

(1) works well if the classes serve little more than acting as a way of bundling related functions together. (Although I prefer to use a `namespace` for such cases.)

(2) works well if the inheritance structure is logical. Don't do it if it isn't.

(3) is a common thing to do.

Comment: I think static will be a good option for me here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

declare the methods as `static`,

```
static double A::f(double variable1)
{
// do stuff on variable 1
}
```

then you can use e.g.

```
double B::g(double variable2)
{
    return A::f(variable2)
}
```

or whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need an object of type `B` to do that:

```
class B {
public:
    A my_a;
    void g() { my_a.f(); }
}
```